BLDC motor torq calculation from specification
I am building an electric skateboard. The goal is to create a simulator that can compute the maximum speed and maximum acceleration from some parameters (weight, motor specifications, wheel diameter, gear ratio, mechanical resistance from air flow, bearing, and friction...).
The first step involves the brushless motor, which is driven by an ESC with FOC. I would like to compute the behavior of the motor from the spec to pick the right KV for my application.
I use these two equations for the model:
$$
U=R⋅I+Kt⋅ω+L\frac{di}{dt}
$$
$$
\tau = Kt⋅I
$$
And I would like to have a better understanding of the datasheet provided by the manufacturer here: Reacher Brushless Motor Datasheet.
I am trying to understand the specifications:
Rpm / V = kv number
Max. Power (W) = Max. Amps (10 sec) × Voltage (Electrical power)
Rated Power (W) = Continuous Current (A) × Voltage (Electrical power)
Max Torque (N·m) = ??
Rated Torque (N·m) = ??
No-load RPM (rpm) = Kv × Voltage
Rated RPM (rpm) = No-load RPM / 1.176471
Max. Amps (10 sec) (A) = ??
Continuous Current (A) = ??

For example, what do the "rated values" really mean? Regarding the rated RPM, I found that it is mostly given by:
$$
RPM_{Rated} = \frac{RPM_{No-load}}{1.176471}
$$
I find this ratio by comparing all data with few python program I wrote with all the datasheet from 6395_v6 series.
I asked the manufacturer to clarify the meaning of these values, but they responded with a vague answer. So I don't have $L$,$K_{\tau}$,$R$ values. But they told me that the current rated value matches the rated torque. So, I tried to compute the torque constant from Kv using the formula $Kt=\frac{60}{2π⋅Kv}$​ and $Kv=\frac{\tau}{I}$​.
When I compute Kt​ from Kv and torque current, I get different values.
So, what am I missing here?
